# Magento 2 - How to affect street address in checkout forms with layout xml/ui arguments

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, forms

I'm trying to set a placeholder on street address fields on shipping address form in checkout.
Followed this example:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html
I've modified my modules `checkout_index_index.xml`.

Most of the fields have now a placeholder in checkout by defining:

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/form/element/my-input</item>
  </item>
</item>
```

Telephone works. The input template is used.

The street address is a group, see `magento-ui/view/frontend/view/frontend/templates/group/group.html`
And it contains 2 input elements.

Can't affect these elements template from layout `checkout_index_index.xml`.

Last I tryed this, without success:

```
<item name="street" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/form/element/my-input</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/form/element/my-input</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

The keys `0` and `1` seem to be correct. I see them in the big JSON in the checkout page source, on the street group:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
  "#checkout":
    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app":  { ... }
}
</script>
```

Anyone knows how street address input fields can be affected?

PS: Input placeholder can be enabled editing the input HTML template like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406440/magento2-checkout-form-how-to-display-placeholder-attribute-value-in-fields/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For street address,you need do some coding.**

At checkout, the fields are rendered from `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger.`

As for showing **placeholder for street** , go to the function `getMultilineFieldConfig`, and paste:

```
if($attributeCode=='street') {
    $line['label'] = $attributeConfig['label'];
}
```

After

```
if ($isFirstLine && isset($attributeConfig['default']) && $attributeConfig['default'] != null) {
        $line['value'] = $attributeConfig['default'];
}
```

And see that magic. I have already tried it with a magento 2 instance, and it is working.

Comment: It works by rewriting AttributeMerger block with a preference. Possibly with a Plugin too. From there I just overloaded the functions I needed where I saw `elementTmpl`. Thank you.

Comment: The function `getMultilineFieldConfig()` is protected, so a plugin won't work here :-/

Comment: how you have done this ..can you share me full code

Answer (score 21):

**The best solution for me was to base yourself in the same method mentioned above: (getMultilineFieldConfig)**

However creating a **NEW MODULE**.

In your new or existing module, add `Magento_Checkout` in the node sequence (**VendorName/ModuleName/etc/module.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Now, set dependency injection for **Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor**

**(VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="vendorname_modulename" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

What is missing is to create the block **(VendorName/ModuleName/Block/LayoutProcessor.php):**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block;

class LayoutProcessor
{
     /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
     public function afterProcess(
         \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
         array  $jsLayout
     ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
        'label' => __('Address'),
        'required' => true,
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 60,
        'type' => 'group',
        'children' => [
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '0',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => true,
                'additionalClasses' => 'additional',
                'label' => __('Street')
            ],
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '1',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => true,
                'label' => __('Number')
            ],
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '2',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => true,
                'label' => __('District')
                ]
            ]
            
        ];

         return $jsLayout;
     }
 }
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: How do I add field validation in these text box,  becoz my default validation not working after doing this ?

Comment: @AshishJagnani,  use `'validation' => ["required-entry"=>true,"max_text_length"=>255,"min_text_length"=>1]` - worked for me

Comment: This is will solve Client side Validation. Say Max Lenth 255. Somebody Inspect & Change. What about server side validation?

Comment: Need to Put Max Length for Street Address Fields. How to do that?

Comment: is it possible to do same for the billing address ?

Comment: is it possible to show this just for logged in users?

Comment: Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Plugin class vendor\presso\Block\LayoutProcessor doesn't exist