# Magento2 How checkout address form fields works?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, address, billing-address

I need to add new field in checkout address form. How can add it ? Also need to convert the city address input field into drop-down field.

Comment: To add new field in checkout you can use this answer:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121520

Comment: How can I convert city field to drop-down and update based on region selection ?