# Magento 2 How to add validation to "street" in checkout address form?

Tags: magento2, validation

Tried to add the following code to add validation for street, but it's not work. How to add the validation for street? Thanks.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress"  xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validate-alpha" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validate-alpha" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="flat" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validate-alphanum-with-spaces" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="floor" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validate-alphanum-with-spaces" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="building" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validate-alphanum-with-spaces" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
<!--                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">-->
                                                                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="validate-hk-address" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                            </item>
<!--                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="validate-hk-address" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>-->
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validate-hk-address" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validate-hk-phone-number" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments> 
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: can you show code for validation in rules.js?

Comment: "validate-alphanum-with-spaces": [
            function(value) {
                return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(value);
            },
            $.mage.__('Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or spaces only in this field.')
        ],

Comment: it's original validation rule of magento.

Comment: plz share your xml file.

Comment: updated content above

Comment: you haven't display your validation for street but here show inside building

Comment: I just need the 2 item names of the 2 lines street in checkout_index_index.xml. For example the item name of zip code is "postcode", but the item name of street is not "street". Do you know the 2 item names for street for adding validation in checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: The Field name for the first street line is street.
The Field name for the second street line is street_second. You can take http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113797/magento-2-how-to-affect-street-address-in-checkout-forms-with-layout-xml-ui-ar as an example to add validation rules to "street".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, Magento's validation for checkout_index_index.xml is not working properly so, you have to insert the rules while you replace the street fields.

You can do this by creating a plugin and insert the fields in Layout AfterProcessor.

```
`namespace/module/etc/frontend/di.xml`
...
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="rewrite-street" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
...
```

And the LayoutProcessorPlugin should look like this:

```
namespace/module/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessorPlugin

...

<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */

public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
        'label' => __('Street Address'),
        'required' => true,
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 60,
        'type' => 'group',
        'additionalClasses' => 'street',
        'children' => [
                [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '0',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
            ],
                [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '1',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => ['required-entry' => false, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
            ]
        ]
    ];
    return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

You can insert in `validation` array any validation rule you want.

Comment: Is this still the only way to add a validation to the street field? Or are validations for checkout_index_index working properly now?

Comment: @KonstantinPatroev i have create same, and set default value for street and i want clear default value when a check box is clicked and it works, but after click in on check box street field gets blank and click on the button to move for payment validation is not working it step up with default value .can check the street field when default value is not set

Answer (score 3):

Creating a plugin and insert the fields in Layout AfterProcessor it is not the best way to solve that issue. The issue regarding the **LayoutProcessorPlugin** is first of all the layout xml (in this case the checkout_index_index.xml) is loaded afterward Magento is coping the all entries out of the attributes over the collected structure and in this case the **LayoutProcessorPlugin** is overriding the stuff.

So my Approach is to use the existing structure.

**Here the (maybe cleaner) Approach**
*This is a set up build in a Magento 2.2.8 Project*

First of all, we need a mixin to validate the field.

Here is my mixin as an example based on the street field but it should be exactly the same for at least all of the address attributes:

*Notice the JavaScript part is only necessary if you need a custom validation*

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/validate'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function (validator) {
        validator.addRule(
            'validate-street-whitespace',
            function (value) {
                var pattern = /\s+\d+\s{0,}\w+$/;

                return value.match(pattern);
            },
            $.mage.__("Invalid street entry! Please add a whitespace between the street name and the house number!")
        );
        return validator;
    };
});
```

Here the setup for you're **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
                'js/validation-mixin': true // pathing depends on you're file location
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This is Javascript wise the complete setup. Instead of the **LayoutProcessorPlugin** you need to update the validate_rules entry in you're attribute table in my case it was the **customer_eav_attribute** my entry look's like this

```
{"max_text_length":255, "min_text_length": 1, "validate-street-whitespace": true}
```

To roll this change out to all of your systems programmatically I set up a patch.
*Notice: This part is a bit custom from my current project but it should provide you're the Idea how to set it up*

```
<?php
namespace YourProject\Config\Setup\UpgradeData;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class UpdateStreetAttribute0x0x72 extends EavSetup
{
    const STREET_ATTRIBUTE_CODE = 'street';

    /**
     * update street attribute
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function install()
    {
        $addressEntityTypeId = $this->getEntityTypeId(AddressMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS);
        $attributeData1 = $this->getAttribute($addressEntityTypeId, self::STREET_ATTRIBUTE_CODE);
        $attributeData1['validate_rules'] = '{"max_text_length":255, "min_text_length": 1, "validate-street-whitespace": true}';
        $this->updateAttribute($addressEntityTypeId, self::STREET_ATTRIBUTE_CODE, $attributeData1);

    }
}
```

Just as one more Notice adding a mixin for `Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator` is only working in the Checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Validation can be added by updating the admin configuration

> Stores -> Configuration -> Attributes -> Customer Address -> Street

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me for city field in checkout.
di.xml of custom module

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="rewrite-street" type="Biztech\Override\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
namespace custom\module\Model\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface;

/**
 * Class LayoutProcessor
 */
class LayoutProcessor
{
    public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['city'] = [
        'required' => true,
    ];
    return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```