# Magento 2 - How to use pattern validation

Tags: magento2, validation, regex

I'm using a plugin to validate the street field (based on https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158101/28803) and I want to use the validation method 'pattern' to test for the following regex:

`.*[0-9].*`

Complete code:

```

```
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
        'label' => __('Street Address'),
        'required' => true,
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 60,
        'type' => 'group',
        'additionalClasses' => 'street',
        'children' => [
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '0',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, 'pattern' => '.*[0-9].*'],
            ],
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '1',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, 'pattern' => ".*[0-9].*"],
            ]
        ]
    ];
    return $jsLayout;
}
```

}
```

However `validation' => ['required-entry' => true, 'pattern' => ".*[0-9].*"],` doesn't work (it generates a blank page on checkout). What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I'm using Magento 2.1.2 with vagrant.

Comment: Try `'pattern' => '^[0-9]$'`

Comment: Hi Ankit, thanks for you help. Unfortunately this doesn't work, it generates the same blank checkout page (see screenshot above). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Check your browser console for javascript errors. There might be something useful there. What you are changing is basically a configuration for the JS on the checkout page. If rendering stops it might be that something breaks the javascript execution.

Comment: I am having the same issue.
The reason is that the pattern function expects a JS regular expression and it is receiving a string instead.

Comment: And did you find the solution @graney?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a different method; by using a custom validation method in rules.js:

```
"validate-adres": [
    function(value) {
        return /[0-9]/.test(value);
    },
    $.mage.__('Your street address must contain a housenumber')
],
```

Combined with the above answer snippet this validates the street address with regex.