# Street Address Validation in Checkout for Magento 2 issue

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, validation, street-address

I am trying to apply a street address validation from the checkout.

In my `checkout_index_index.xml` file, I've added this:

```
<referenceBlock  name="checkout.root">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="maximum-length" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="maximum-length" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="maximum-length" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

I am trying to add a max length for the street address fields (0,1,2). I've read this post:[Magento 2 How to add validation to "street" in checkout address form?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125864/magento-2-how-to-add-validation-to-street-in-checkout-address-form) , but I don't want to create a new module for this, I am trying to fix this via the layout xml file. Can you suggest please, what I did wrong ? Any advice are welcome! :)

Thank you

**[UPDATE]**
I also tried this one, but doesn't work:

```
<item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="maximum-length" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="maximum-length" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="maximum-length" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by updating the admin configuration

> Stores -> Configuration -> Attributes -> Customer Address -> Street

[image: Update config here:]

Comment: For whatever daft reason Magento decided, this is only available for the $30K+/yr EE. Why remove a very basic feature like this from OS?