# magento2 billing address form street filed validation not working

Tags: magento2, checkout

```
  // Street address
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
                ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']
                ['children']['street']['children'][0]['validation']['max_text_length'] = 50;
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
                ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']
                ['children']['street']['children'][1]['validation']['max_text_length'] = 50;

    $payment_methods = ['ewayrapid','paypal_express','banktransfer'];


    foreach ($payment_methods as $payment) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
                [$payment.'-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street']['children'][0]['validation']['max_text_length'] = 50;
                
        
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
                [$payment.'-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street']['children'][1]['validation']['max_text_length'] = 50;
    }
    return $jsLayout;
```

Comment: Can you please brief us more?

Comment: Can you check pls https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125864/magento-2-how-to-add-validation-to-street-in-checkout-address-form