# Magento 2 : How to add placeholder text to street fields in checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, template, forms

In back-end I've set the street address to have 3 lines.

I'd like to put a different placeholder in each field:

- Street
- Building / Apartment
- Area

This way user can enter data in a more structured way.

A similar question can be found here:

[Magento 2 - How to affect street address in checkout forms with layout xml/ui arguments](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113797/magento-2-how-to-affect-street-address-in-checkout-forms-with-layout-xml-ui-ar)

However the answers does not provide a solution to include placeholders in **street address fields.**

What I want to achieve is setting a **different placeholder for each street address field**.

My code:

app/code/Jsp/Placeholder/etc/module.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Jsp_Placeholder" setup_version="2.0.0" />
</config>
```

app/code/Jsp/Placeholder/registration.php :

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  'Jsp_Placeholder',
  __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Jsp/Placeholder/etc/di.xml :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger">
    <plugin name="shippingAddress" type="Jsp\Placeholder\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger\Plugin"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Jsp/Placeholder/Plugin/Checkout/Block/Checkout/AttributeMerger/Plugin.php :

```
<?php
namespace Jsp\Placeholder\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger;
class Plugin {
  public function afterMerge(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $subject, $result)
  {
    if (array_key_exists('street', $result)) {
      $result['street']['children'][0]['placeholder'] = __('Calle y número exterior');
      $result['street']['children'][1]['placeholder'] = __('Interior / Edificio / Depto.');
      $result['street']['children'][2]['placeholder'] = __('Colonia');
    }
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: After adding this module have you did these step :
1. enable module : sudo bin/magento module:enable Jsp_Placeholder
2. upgrade setup : sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. compile setup : sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile
Have you did all these ?

Comment: These code is perfectly working with default checkout address form in magento 2.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add these file in any of your custom module :

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="2.0.0" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  'Vendor_ModuleName',
  __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger">
    <plugin name="shippingAddress" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger\Plugin"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger\Plugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger;

class Plugin
{
  public function afterMerge(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $subject, $result)
  {
    if (array_key_exists('street', $result)) {
      $result['street']['children'][0]['placeholder'] = __('Flat No/House No/Building No');
      $result['street']['children'][1]['placeholder'] = __('Street Address');
      $result['street']['children'][2]['placeholder'] = __('Landmark');
    }

    return $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should I add the `di.xml` file? I don't have any custom modules

Comment: Pl check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've created the module following your instructions but the placeholders don't show up yet. The module is enabled, I clean cache, and run setup:upgrade. Have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Write your exact code of all files of module in your question what you have tried.

Comment: I just updated my question with the code I tried

Comment: It worked, thanks! The problem was some customizations I had made to the checkout template.

Comment: How to prepopulate the field and also want to add multiple fields ?

Comment: even for me it is not working.. i followed whatever steps mentioned..kindly help me

Comment: @AshishJagnani is it not better to place the di.xml in the frontend folder? Since it is not used in the adminhtml.

Comment: @AshishJagnani Thanks for this solution. But how can we translate the placeholders in this case?

Comment: How Can I add placeholder to custom field

Comment: By creating the Plugin for `AttributeMerger`, it will be called many times for every attribute in the checkout. I think it would be better (although slightly harder) to create a Plugin for `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::process`

Answer (score 0):

I would create an after Plugin for `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::process`. This way it would be called only once.

The plugin would look like:

```php
public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject, $result, $jsLayout)
{

    $streetLines = &$result['components']["checkout"]["children"]["steps"]["children"]["billing-step"]["children"]
                ["payment"]["children"]["afterMethods"]["children"]["billing-address-form"]["children"]
                ["form-fields"]["children"]["street"]["children"];

    $streetLines[0]['label'] = new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Street Address'); #change if you want to
    $streetLines[0]['placeholder'] = __('Flat No/House No/Building No');
# ... and so on for $streetLines[1], 2, 3, etc

    return $result;
}
```

The above solution would be for the billing address, but you can change shipping address as well, by modifying it accordingly to your needs.