# Magento2 - How to add placeholder to knockoutjs field?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, knockoutjs

I'm editing `app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Checkout\web\template\cart\shipping-estimation.html`
which handles the shipping and tax estimation in shopping cart page.
Here is the code:

```
<form method="post" id="shipping-zip-form" class="shipping-zip-form">
<fieldset class="fieldset estimate">
    <p class="field note" data-bind="text: isVirtual ? $t('Enter your billing address to get a tax estimate.') : $t('Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate.')"></p>
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('address-fieldsets') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
</fieldset>
```

from there, I know that it's being generated by knockout.js, so I searched around and found `vendor\magento\module-ui\view\frontend\web\templates\form\element\input.html`

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
value: value,
valueUpdate: 'keyup',
hasFocus: focused,
attr: {
    name: inputName,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    'aria-describedby': noticeId,
    id: uid,
    disabled: disabled
}" />
```

and I also looked at this file

```
vendor\magento\module-ui\view\frontend\web\templates\form\field.html
```

which has this code

```
    <label class="label" data-bind="attr: { for: element.uid }">
        <!-- ko if: element.label -->
        <span data-bind="text: element.label"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </label>
```

So from those 2 files, I assume the placeholder must be inserted to the 'element', and then in `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml` , I tried this:

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
    <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.postcode</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string">testPlaceholder</item>
</item>
```

and I added this in `vendor\magento\module-ui\view\frontend\web\templates\form\field.html`

```
provider: -<span data-bind="text: element.provider"></span>-
placeholder: -<span data-bind="text: element.placeholder"></span>-
```

which outputs:

```
provider: -checkoutProvider- placeholder: --
```

Placeholder doesn't show up in front end.
So, any idea how to add the placeholder there?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `data-bind="text: placeholder"`?

Comment: That wont work ben, m2 has ko bindingHandlers for placeholders. Its just determining where the placeholder is being generated, finding the Handler is key.

Comment: Ah damn it, was worth a try :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, as I've only looked at it for around 15 minutes. But it looks as thought the placeholder is coming from the **Abstract.js** this file is located

```
Vender\Theme\Magento_Ui\web\js\form\element\abstract.js
```

This is the core location for it.

If you look at **line 27** you'll see:

```
placeholder: ' ',
```

I am assuming this is the main Element that is extended. I dumped some data into this, I used the label:

```
placeholder: '${ $.label }',
```

This will take the parent label and drop it as a placeholder into any input with a label.

[image][image]

However what I think M2 want you to do is extend this Element again and build upon it, but I could be wrong. If anyone has more info on this please feel free to share.

Comment: Thanks. this will at least add the placeholder there. Still don't know how to edit the placeholder content though.. So far I've checked `vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor.php`. I can actually edit the label there, but not add placeholder.

Comment: The placeholder isn't generated by php, its done through KO - you need to be looking inside of the js

Comment: I found this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132718/magento-2-how-to-add-placeholder-text-to-street-fields-in-checkout), and then I add this `$jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']
  ['children']['address-fieldsets']['children']['postcode']['placeholder'] = __('Test Placeholder');`  in LayoutProcessor.php just before `return $jsLayout` and it actually works.

Comment: I tried this.. in shipping address checkout I need the placeholder for all fields.. after applying this placeholder , instead of taking shippingAddress.(name) it is taking admin field form elements via ko..what to do?

Comment: Correct answer +1

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap your placholder item in the config item.

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
```

Add it like this below

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
     <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.postcode</item>
     <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
     <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string">Enter Postcode</item>
     </item>
</item>
```

You can add this code in your local checkout_cart_index.xml
/app/design/frontend/{your_theme}/default/Magento_Checkout/layout/

this is an example for the shipping estimator in the cart page, this will add the placeholder text "Enter Postcode"

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
 <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="block-shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="address-fieldsets" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array"> 
                                            <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.postcode</item>
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
                                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string">Enter Postcode</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
     </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (at least for 2.4+)