# Add placeholder and remove all labels in Magento 2 Checkout

Tags: checkout, layout, template, forms, magento2.2

Searched a lot but didn't found anything removing the

Lables like "First Name, Last Name, City, Address, Email, Phone etc"

Add Placeholders in all "shipping fields" and "sign In" places. 
After Login Placeholders in "new add address popup"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACVIF.jpg

Please help me struggling from so many days didn't found any exact thing.

Comment: I've tried this and it's not working. Has anything been changed in recent Magento code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't find ***any proper solution but give you quick and good solution***.

Magento checkout's `input fields` are render by  `Magento_Ul` module **component's file**

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/input.html

***On this files, you need to changes***

`placeholder: placeholder` to  `placeholder: label`

So, first copy ***this html  to your frontend theme*** folder

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Themename}/Magento_Ui/web/templates/form/element/

On this `input.html` add this code:

```
<input class="admin__control-text" type="text"
    data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: label,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled
    }"/>
```

Then, you need to add `_extend.less` at **your theme folder**

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Themename}/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less

add this code for hidden the label css:

```
.checkout-index-index label{display:none}
```

Then You must flush cache by run

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Or **delete all files from `view_procecced, cache,page_cache`.**

Then you should static content deploy

> `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: This Solution is working but partially. Some Placeholders are not coming and some Lables (Street Address) is not hidden via the above solution.
Screenshot After the solution
https://imgur.com/iuzL93e

Answer (score 1):

We have already solved this problem/feature in several projects with the following module:

https://github.com/mediarox/module-checkout-placeholder

It uses a so called "LayoutProcessor" to change the address fields on PHP side.

The principle can be seen in the documentation in the chapter "Add custom fields that influence other Checkout fields":

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_custom_checkbox.html

The "LayoutProcessor" copies the label string into the placeholder variable ("placeholder" property of the field). So you don't need to customize the input template as Amit mentioned.

Comment: Great extension implementation, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing in every input type template the most common and effective way is to change in abstract.js and make every template to take placeholder

`Vender\Theme\Magento_Ui\web\js\form\element\abstract.js`

Line no 30 as of now, change `placeholder: false` to `placeholder: '${ $.label }'`.

Of-course override in custom theme or even better to make js mixin to replace property of ui-component is much more preferred.

Original answer at -
[Magento2 - How to add placeholder to knockoutjs field?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177145/magento2-how-to-add-placeholder-to-knockoutjs-field)