# Magento 2: How to make the forgotten password captcha input field's label a placeholder?

Tags: magento2, captcha, password-recovery, labels, placeholder

I am trying to make captcha input label a placeholder, not label.

I followed the following instructions for doing the same thing on the checkout:
https://diweirich.com/magento-2-using-placeholders-in-form-fields/ 
[Add placeholder and remove all labels in Magento 2 Checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197650/add-placeholder-and-remove-all-labels-in-magento-2-checkout).

But it doesn't affect the captcha input field. Can any suggest where I need to edit to achieve a placeholder as opposed to label for the captcha input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**=> Copy :**

> /vendor/magento/module-captcha/view/frontend/templates/default.phtml

**=> to :**

> /app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Captcha/templates/

**=> Remove :**

```
<label for="captcha_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormId()) ?>" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please type the letters below')) ?></span></label>
```

and add a placeholder to the `input` element:

```
<input name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(\Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE) ?>[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormId()) ?>]" type="text" class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" id="captcha_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormId()) ?>" placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please type the letters above')) ?>" />
```

*Clear static files and cache to see the changes.*

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this Following Script, This will solve your problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'], function ($) 
{
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $("label:contains('Please type captcha here')").hide();
        $(#Your_Form_ID).find('input[name*="captcha"]').attr("placeholder", "Please type captcha here");
    })
});
</script>
```