# Remove <label> tags from shipping address fields on the checkout page in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, labels

I am trying to remove all the `<label>` tags from a shipping address form on the checkout page.

[Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197650/add-placeholder-and-remove-all-labels-in-magento-2-checkout?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-197656) is the answer to hide those labels using CSS.

I am trying to move those labels below the input fields.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The form uses templates from the *Magento UI* module. You can override these in your custom theme.

The main template you should override is `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/field.html`.

There are some exceptions. E.g. the *Email Address* field is part of the *Checkout* module and to modify that you should override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/email.html`. Then there are also the address line fields which don't use labels but instead a fieldset with a legend. To modify this you could either use CSS to change the position of the legend or override `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/group/group.html` to use something else instead of the legend.