# Magento 2 Checkout - How to replace labels with placeholders

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, labels, placeholder, uielement

In the Magento 2 Checkout, i need to replace the form input labels (Firstname, Lastname, City etc) with placeholders (text that will show inside the input box).

I found this solution https://diweirich.com/magento-2-using-placeholders-in-form-fields/ but not sure if this is the correct approach as it overrides labels to be considered placeholders.

And here the same workaround is suggested [Add placeholder and remove all labels in Magento 2 Checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197650/add-placeholder-and-remove-all-labels-in-magento-2-checkout)

Any solution is welcome.

Comment: Yes you can go with second link, @AmitBera 's answer is correct.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar i know that Amit's way works, but i'm looking for the best scalable way leaving labels as they are and instead finding a way to use placeholders.