# Magento 2 checkout address labels

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

How can I add a label to checkout addresses fields?
[image]

Comment: label Or placeholder ?

Comment: @Pawan in my case I need both

Comment: You can add placeholder by using: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132718/magento-2-how-to-add-placeholder-text-to-street-fields-in-checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can need to create a module and rewrite street in di.xml**

**di.xml**

```
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="rewrite-street" type="Vendor\ModuelName\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="20"/>
</type>
```

**Create LayoutProcessorPlugin**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
            //'label' => __('Street Address'), I removed main label
            'required' => false, //turn false because I removed main label
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 0,
            'type' => 'group',
            'additionalClasses' => 'street',
            'children' => [
                [
                    'label' => __('Label 1'),
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '0',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => __('Label 2'),
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '1',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => __('Label 3'),
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '2',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => __('Label 4'),
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '3',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => false, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
                ],
            ]
        ];
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

You can try above code and modify as per your requirement.

Comment: Is there something less "intrusive" and that can be modified for each store or website ?